# What's a Model in MVC. Should I understand it as a reflection of a view in terms of data contained in it ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So, should Model be considered as reflection of a view in terms of data. For example the model of a contact form would be : Name, Email Address, WebsiteName and Description ? Is this correct conceptually ?

Thanks
V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have explained is a ViewModel essentially: a Model that is tailored to one View.  But the definition of a Model would be *the objects that send information to the database, perform business functions, and are just the representation of the **domain** of the application*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is one case of model. Model can also be business domain rules.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

> The model manages the behaviour and data of the application domain,
>   responds to requests for information about its state (usually from the
>   view), and responds to instructions to change state (usually from the
>   controller). In event-driven systems, the model notifies observers
>   (usually views) when the information changes so that they can react.

Answer (score 0):

In general, **yes**. Sometimes it's tedious, but a 1:1 ratio of "view" model to view works very well, and keeps concerns separated.

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteName { get; set; }
}
```

If you were to use Visual Studio's (**assuming version 3 of MVC and Razor syntax**) built-in scaffolding to generate a view inheriting this view model, it would look something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ContactFormViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    ...
```

This gives you a couple things:

- A little CSS styling (again, just the default templating)
- **Validation**
- **1 Model** to modify when the contact form logic changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There are two ways to look at a model in an MVC application. The two have a lot of overlaps, but are not necessarily the same.

- View Model -- contains a model of data to be created, deleted, edited or shown in a view.
- Entity Model -- contains a model of a data set from a datasource to be created, deleted, edited or shown in a view.

As you can see, in most cases this will be the same thing. There are situations where thinking of a view model will make more sense.